# Why database or table not created when I run my spring and Hibernate project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When i run my project It sun successfully but table is not created. where i am doing wrong

**My Hibernate configuration class**

```
package com.quickstart.com.springmvc.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.quickstart.com.springmvc.config" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfigration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.quickstart.com.springmvc.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        System.out.println(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

My SpringConfigration class

```
package com.quickstart.com.springmvc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.quickstart.com.springmvc")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

My User Class

```
package com.quickstart.com.springmvc.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="Age")
    private int age;
    @Column(name="Password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="Contact")
    private String contact;
    @Column(name="User_Name")
    private String username;

    User(){

    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    User(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }



}
```

my properties file

> jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jdbc.url =
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateTestDB jdbc.username = root
>   jdbc.password = root hibernate.dialect =
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect hibernate.show_sql = true
>   hibernate.format_sql = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot this option `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in your properties :

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
```

This property can have the following values :

- `create` creates the schema, destroying previous data
- `create-drop` drop the schema when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly, typically when the application is stopped.
- `update` update the schema.
- `validate` validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Add a property in your hibernate configuration properties file

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto  = create
```

The other available values are "update" "create-drop" "validate" etc
See  "Table 3.7. Miscellaneous Properties" https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html